# New tag for Simulation-nodes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Now that *Simulation Nodes* are here.  Should we create a new tag called [simulation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation-nodes) like we have for [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes)?

Comment: Basically yes, but *"it's here"*, is currently not correct, because it has not reached a stable version yet *(15.5.2023)*. Establishing functions that are only available in alpha/beta versions as their own tags is therefore premature in my opinion.

Comment: I just wanted to get ahead of it they announced that it will be in the 3.6 version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yq_2qsv1MI . Things related to Simulation-nodes has been showing up for awhile and getting this stuff tagged / labeled correctly will make it easier to search for things in the future... https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=simulation+nodes

Comment: From this point of view: Yes, Since it is (fairly) certain that *Simulation Nodes* will come sooner or later, it would be good to do some preliminary work here and tag the questions correctly already now (Even though they may not have much relevance in the long run at the moment). However, there was once a tag [tag:geometry-nodes-fields], which was also merged with [tag:geometry-nodes]. Strictly speaking, *Simulation Nodes* are simply *Geometry Nodes*. Currently, there are actually too many tags, and it would be better to clean up the mess and merge tags instead of creating more derivatives.

Comment: Good point. Given that question about it are bound to come pouring in soon now would be the time to create the tag (or synonym). Whether we actually want a dedicated [tag:simulation-nodes] tag or not is something else that needs discussion. As quellenform correctly points out it seems to me like just another type of Geometry Nodes that doesn't warrant a tag of its own. @RickT Do you think we'd benefit from a dedicated tag for simulation nodes? Do you see any situation we'd benefit from a tag specifically for simulations or would the old tag suffice?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Honestly, I go back and forth.  On one hand simulation-nodes is part of geometry nodes as @quellenform so `correctly` stated, on the other hand it really is it's own subgroup.  We currently have the `modifier` tag but we also have the `screw-modifier` tag  and the `bevel` tag (should be a `bevel-modifer` tag also) but we have no `weld-modifier` tag.  What are the requirements for a tag to be created.  Note this can quickly get out of hand and we start creating a tag for everything (Like putting post-it notes / labels on everything hahaha https://imgur.com/NWzeK6H)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been thinking a bit more about this and came to the conclusion that for the time being at least we do need the [simulation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation-nodes) tag.

It is true our tag system is a bit inconsistent at the time, we do have tags for some modifiers but not others.

The general (lack of) rule so far has been creating tags on a need-to basis. Users, some times newly arrived, create tags that lay around for a while, and we ended up adding wikis to them making them became more permanent. Some times in retrospect we come to the conclusion we don't need a certain tag and create a synonym after the fact.

I do think some specific modifier tags do have their value, they help us filter for more specific or substantial modifiers (like boolean or bevel), or distinguish between modifiers and their homonym edit mode operators.

As for the Simulation Nodes I'd vote for keeping it as dedicated tag not because they are distinct from regular [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes), but to help distinguish from legacy physics simulations, which I suspect will eventually be phased out in favor and the new system.

It may additionally be relevant in contrast with regular Geometry Nodes, since unlike the old Fields, (which became an integral part of the broader geometry nodes) physics simulations will always act as "box" inside a more general node tree, with well defined "gated" entry and exit points.

While input can be added at any point in the simulation box, output will only happen with a *Simulation Output* node. I haven't yet dug into the specifics, but I suspect this will open the door to trying to solve certain issues with the subset of nodes that can be used inside this simulation area, along with any additional limitations that may or may not apply.

For these reasons I'd argue to create a [simulation-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation-nodes) and maintain tag to distinguish from the old physics simulation both for historical purposes and for any users for any reason stuck with older Blender versions.

Let me know if you have any arguments against it. If we all agree now would be a good time to create it, since questions about simulation are likely to start rising in volume in the near future.

Comment: OK, let's do this, I agree for now. I'm not quite convinced yet, since more tags don't make the tags less, but in this case a distinction might be handy for the future. And if the questions are tagged, they can always be retagged afterwards if the decision didn't turn out to be useful after all. I am so free and take care of it right away....

Comment: Yes, we can later remove the tag if we no longer see the need for it. It is easier to remove an unwanted tag, then it is to retroactively try to tag a large backlog of existing questions with an new tag.